# Regex and ignore whitespace

Tags: regex, scripting, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have the following regex that I am using to match on various credit card numbers within a string search of files.  However, if there is a space before or after the pattern to match, then the match will fail.

```
$CC_Regex = "^(\d{4}-){3}\d{4}$|^(\d{4} ){3}\d{4}$|^\d{16}$"
```

For example, it will match the top three, but will not match the bottom three.

```
1111-2323-2312-3434
1234343425262837
1111 2323 2312 3434

1111-2323-2312-3434 
 1234343425262837
 1111 2323 2312 3434
```

Out of the bottom three, the first one has a space at the end of it, the second one has a space before it, and the third one has a space before and after it.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It it matters, I am using this within Windows PowerShell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It would be easy enough to augment the regex to handle whitespace at the front and end:

```
^\s*(?:(\d{4}-){3}\d{4}|(\d{4} ){3}\d{4}|\d{16})\s*$
```

but it seems more prudent to take the string, remove everything except digits, and then check if it's a 16-digit number:

```
$result = $subject -creplace '[^0-9]+', ''
$found = $result -cmatch '^[0-9]{16}$'
```

After all, who knows what ideas people might have for formatting - several spaces between groups, mixes of spaces and dashes etc...

Comment: You beat me to it by seconds. :)

Comment: @Tim - thanks for the information.  I just tested this and it seems to catch the case where there is a single space at the end of the matched string.  It does not seem to catch the cases where there is a space before the matched string or the case where there is a space both before and after the matched string.

Comment: @Tim - I am not sure if one is able to perform the second item that you mention within PowerShell.  Regardless though, it seems to be a very valid point.

Comment: @Tim, you made the same mistake as I did in my answer - you didn't notice there are `$|^`s inside the regex, so `\s*` has to be added in more places.

Comment: @Jakub: Oh, right. Thanks! But instead of adding more `\s`s, I removed the now-superfluous `^`s and `$`s.

Comment: And, by the way, American Express card numbers only have 15 digits, some Diners Club have only 14.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how specifically to do this in PowerShell, but it'd be a lot easier to use some sort of replace() function to get rid of the spaces (or the equivalent in PowerShell).

```
replace(' ', '');
```

**EDIT:** Actually, it'd make more sense to remove *everything* that's not a digit first. You could do that with RegEx easily:

```
[^0-9]+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$CC_Regex = "^\s*(\d{4}-){3}\d{4}\s*$|^\s*(\d{4} ){3}\d{4}\s*$|^\s*\d{16}\s*$"
```

will make it match even if leading or trailing whitepsace is present (`\s` means any whitespace character).

Comment: thanks for the information.  I just tested this and it seems to catch the case where there is a single space at the end of the matched string.  It does not seem to catch the cases where there is a space before the matched string or the case where there is a space both before and after the matched string.

Comment: @John, I've corrected the regex. Thanks for pointing out the mistake and sorry for providing a wrong answer in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

```
$CC_Regex = "(?:\d{4}[- ]?){3}\d{4}"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this `^(?<myregex>\s{0,}\d{4}-{0,}\s{0,}\d{4}-{0,}\s{0,}\d{4}-{0,}\s{0,}\d{4}).*?`